# How to open PDFs securely?

Tags: pdf

I'm new in Linux and information security. I wonder how I can "isolate" a PDF file in order to read it securely.

How can I mitigate potentional risks and open a PDF in a "secure way"?

*I would like to do so on a Linux Debian machine*

Comment: If you want to be paranoid safe: don't "open" them in a viewer application but convert them to an image.

Comment: It might not appear as an exact duplicate, but the existing answers pretty precisely address your question.

Comment: Open With... Google Chrome; way safer than Acrobat Reader...